# fb invite friends not working in ie 8

Tags: php, facebook, internet-explorer-8

i used the FB API invite friends to let users invite their friends to my app. all working fine in Chrome and FF but not in IE 8. when i click it, on the bottom of IE, will show "Error on page". the error would point at connect.facebook.net part.  below is the code;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<script>
FB.init({
appId:'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
cookie:true,
status:true,
xfbml:true
});

function FacebookInviteFriends()
{
FB.ui({
method: 'apprequests',
message: 'Come Upload Your Own Photo For A Chance To WIN!',
  }, requestCallback);
}

function requestCallback(response)
{
if(response && response.request) {
     // Here, requests have been sent, facebook gives you the request and the array of     recipients
     //console.log(response);

     location.href='final.php';

} else {
alert("You need to invite friends in order to proceed");
     // No requests sent, you can do what you want 
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: are you including any other Jquery or JS plugin..? Sometimes in IE, facebook API conflicts with other plugins..

Answer (score 0):

try to add domain parameter in FB.init , it works in ie8

fb init will like :

```
FB.init({
appId:'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
domain:'yourdomain.com',
cookie:true,
status:true,
xfbml:true
});
```

Comment: added but still not functioning. IE is showing has problem at;

    <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>